# Problema com Permissões Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

Enviei um novo apk para a Google Play Store para fazer upgrade a uma outra aplicação, no entanto, na consola, na secção de permissões necessárias vejo que a permissão android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS é necessária nesta versão e que os utilizadores antigos não poderão fazer update mas fazer nova instalação. No entanto, esta permissão não está no manifest.

Alguém sabe o que poderá estar a lançar esta permissão?

No manifest tenho as seguintes permissões:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="*******.fileprovider.READ" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: Tiago, o site é em **portugues**. Traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Actualizado @Articunohexacampão

Answer (score 1):

O problema é uma biblioteca que estou a utilizar na minha aplicação e tem essa permissão.
Para ver isso, no Android Studio, selecionei o ficheiro de manifest e depois carreguei na tab Merged Manifest, aí consegui ver o que estava a adicionar essa permissão.
No manifest da minha aplicação adicionei a seguinte linha:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" tools:node="remove" />`